# Can't get MetaMask wallet address on Firefox but Chrome is fine

Tags: web3js, metamask

I'm trying to get the current wallet address of MetaMask on my Firefox 67 but I keep getting nothing (empty array), except it says my MetMask is locked. But on Chrome 74 it works. FYI, my MetaMask is NOT locked at all.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Check if Web3 has been injected by the browser:
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // You have a web3 browser! Continue below!
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

        var version = web3.version;

        //Get wallet info in the form of Javascript object
        var account = web3.eth.accounts;

        //Get the current MetaMask selected/active wallet
        walletAddress = account.givenProvider.selectedAddress;

        //Check if Metamask is locked
        if (!empty(walletAddress)){

            //Detect if the user changes the account on MetaMask
            window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
                console.log("MetaMask account change. Reloading...");
                window.location.reload(); 
            })

            //If not locked, continue to run the app
            startApp(web3);

          } else {

            //If locked, alert user to unlock their MetaMask
            if (alert("<?php _e('Your MetaMask is locked. Please unlock with your password and then press OK below.', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?>")){
            } else {
                window.location.reload(); 
            }
          }

    } else {
        if (alert("<?php _e('No MetaMask plugin detected. Please install MetaMask digital wallet at www.metamask.io', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?>")){
        } else {
            window.location.reload(); 
        }
    }
});
```

I also tried the two options below but failed.

```
    var accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }       
    });

var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
          if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== account) {
            account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
            window.location.reload();
          }
        }, 100);
```

Comment: Check the privacy and security setting of metmask

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a few tries by turning of Privacy Mode, it worked. I guess I wasn't aware of this Privacy Mode. It was turned off in my Chrome by default but on by default in my FireFox MetaMask 6.6.2. Read this, https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

Answer (score 0):

You can try with web3.eth.defaultAccount and it works great with multiple addresses on both chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

@warnerque

Exactly, now to access the accounts you need to ask the user for permission in the web browser.

For all future readers you can do a simple block of the code to access the account here:

```
const ethereum = window.ethereum;
const web3 = window.web3;
const web3Instance = new Web3(ethereum);
const enabledWeb3 = await ethereum.enable();
const account = await web3Instance.eth.getAccounts();
const accountAddress = await account[0];
```